# How to achieve performance testing on smpp protocol

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, sms-gateway, smpp

I'm trying to achieve performance testing for mobile originated(MO). I want to simulate mobile to application communication. anyone with SMS performance testing experience or knowledge can guide me on how to load test SMSC. Using an open-source tool preferably JMeter.

Comment: Your question is not clear. If you saying mobile originating and say that it's using SMPP that means that the message that is originated from the mobile is not an Person2Application (SMS) but an Application2NotSpecified. So actually your using your internet connection to create an SMPP bind with your SMSC. Is that right?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest would be using i.e. [jSMPP](https://github.com/opentelecoms-org/jsmpp) library calls from the [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) using [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)

There are several useful [examples](https://github.com/opentelecoms-org/jsmpp/tree/master/jsmpp-examples) including [StressClient](https://github.com/opentelecoms-org/jsmpp/blob/master/jsmpp-examples/src/main/java/org/jsmpp/examples/StressClient.java) which seems to be exactly what you're looking for.

So just download the [.jar](https://search.maven.org/search?q=org.jsmpp), drop it to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath), restart JMeter to pick it up and start coding your use cases with the JSR223 Samplers.

You may also be interested in [How to Write a plugin for JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/extending/jmeter_tutorial.pdf) if you need to share the implementation with not-too-technical people.